# Mysql group by day in a date_time field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Is it ever possible to have a query that selects rows grouped by the day or month from a table that has a date_time filed holding full date_time value?

[image]

I need to get the sum of sr13, r4, huawei for each day.
Any idea of how I can do it would be heartfully appreciated!

Comment: do you have any filters to restrict data to a month? If you group by day then you might get rows from different months for same day.

Comment: $counter_result = $this->db->query("select date_time, sum(r4) as sum_r4, sum(sr13) as sum_sr13, sum(huawei) as sum_huawei from cdrcount where date_time like '2013-03-%' group by date_time");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATE()` to extract the date from the value,

```
SELECT  DATE(date_time) datetime,
        SUM(sr13) total_sr13,
        SUM(r4) total_4
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY DATE(date_time)
```

Comment: What if I want to group by month.. to get the sum of the three(r4,sr13,huawei) for each month?

Comment: Bingo.. I got it..: GROUP BY month(date_time);

Comment: you can use either `MONTH()` or `MONTHNAME()` together with `YEAR()`, ex `SELECT YEAR(date_time), MONTHNAME(date_time),.... GROUP BY YEAR(date_time), MONTHNAME(date_time)`